# Getting error Error injecting: org.jacoco.maven.AgentMojo while maven build

Tags: java, maven, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am trying to build a maven project but its giving me below error.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jacoco/core/runtime/AgentOptions

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9:prepare-agent (agent) on project app: Execution agent of goal org.jacoco:ja
coco-maven-plugin:0.7.9:prepare-agent failed: A required class was missing while executing org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9:prepare-agent: org/jacoc
o/core/runtime/AgentOptions
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/t/.m2/repository1/org/jacoco/jacoco-maven-plugin/0.7.9/jacoco-maven-plugin-0.7.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/t/.m2/repository1/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : org.jacoco.core.runtime.AgentOptions
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Even though I have  jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9 & org.jacoco.core-0.7.9 in maven repo its giving this error.

I am using mvn clean install command to build the application .
Further I also tried building with -U flag

Lastly, when I build it using -X option I see below stack trace

```
    [INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9:prepare-agent (agent) @ ncso-app-pso ---
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:pom:0.7.9, already updated during this session.
[WARNING] The POM for org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:jar:0.7.9 is missing, no dependency information available
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=50400, ConflictMarker.markTime=25500, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=1, ConflictIdSorter.grap
hTime=7100, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=12700, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=1, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=
56700, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=1, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=8846200, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=181500}
[DEBUG] org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:jar:0.7.9:
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1:runtime
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:jar:0.7.9
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9:prepare-agent from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9, pa
rent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05]
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.jacoco.maven.AgentMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jacoco/core/runtime/AgentOptions
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods (Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods (Class.java:1975)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints (InjectionPoint.java:688)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields (InjectionPoint.java:380)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:164)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies (InjectorImpl.java:613)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup (InjectorImpl.java:569)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding (InjectorImpl.java:555)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:884)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive (InjectorImpl.java:805)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:282)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:214)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:1006)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1038)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1001)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call (InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext (InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get (InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:519)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jacoco.core.runtime.AgentOptions
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass (ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods (Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods (Class.java:1975)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints (InjectionPoint.java:688)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields (InjectionPoint.java:380)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:164)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies (InjectorImpl.java:613)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup (InjectorImpl.java:569)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding (InjectorImpl.java:555)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:884)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive (InjectorImpl.java:805)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:282)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:214)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:1006)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1038)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1001)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call (InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext (InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get (InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:519)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

Comment: `AgentOptions` is indeed supposed to be loaded from `org.jacoco.core`. Can you run the build command with debug enabled (`-X`) and check if there are any errors in the resolved plugin dependency list? And perhaps add what maven and java version you run this on. Have you tried updating to plugin version `0.8.x`?

Comment: Yes, I tried to upgrade plugin version to 0.8.1 but it gives same error.

Comment: Updated stack trace in question

Comment: `[WARNING] The POM for org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:jar:0.7.9 is missing, no dependency information available` this is weird, in my `.m2` there is a pom available for this artifact. Can you check `.m2\repository\org\jacoco\jacoco-maven-plugin\0.7.9` if it contains `jacoco-maven-plugin-0.7.9.pom`? I would recommend to remove `org\jacoco` from your local m2 and try again.

Comment: We can also see `[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:pom:0.7.9, already updated during this session.`, this could indicate that there was a problem downloading the pom file. Are there any errors in `.m2\repository\org\jacoco\jacoco-maven-plugin\0.7.9\_remote.repositories`? Is it trying to download from `central`, or do you have any custom `pluginRepositories`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the maven build command with argument `-X` to enable debug logging.
With this output you now see the following line in your log:

`[WARNING] The POM for org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:jar:0.7.9 is missing, no dependency information available`

Normally the class `AgentOptions` is loaded from `org.jacoco.core`, which is a dependency of the plugin. But without the pom file, the maven build process doesn't know this and even though you have that jar file in your local repository, it will not be used due to the missing pom file.

In my local m2 i do have the following pom file: `.m2\repository\org\jacoco\jacoco-maven-plugin\0.7.9\jacoco-maven-plugin-0.7.9.pom`. This leads me to believe there is something wrong with your downloaded copy.

I have verified this causes a problem by removing the `dependencies` list in the local copy of the plugins' pom file, and then i get the same error message in the build process.

As a solution you can clear the contents of `.m2\repository\org\jacoco\` and try your build again, then all correct plugin files and dependencies should be downloaded again from maven central.

We can also see `[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:pom:0.7.9, already updated during this session.`, this could indicate that there was a problem downloading the pom file. Are there any errors in `.m2\repository\org\jacoco\jacoco-maven-plugin\0.7.9\_remote.repositories`?

Is it trying to download from `central`, or do you have any custom `pluginRepositories` that might not have the complete pom file?  You can see your entire pom file by running `mvn help:effective-pom`.

Normally that should include the following from the [super pom](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.5/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html):

```xml
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
```

More extreme measures could be to download a newer version of maven, or clear your entire local `.m2` (create a backup if you have important files in there).

Those would be the places to look to resolve this issue.